# CLLocation doesn't work - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cllocationmanager

I have a tabbar project in xcode and on the first view i need to find my GPS location and I need to save longitude and latitude on two variables on the appdelegate. Here some code:

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{ 
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;     
}    
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "CampeggiandoAppDelegate.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize locationManager;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_home2"];
        self.tabBarItem.title=@"Home";
    }
    return self;
}
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=500.0f;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    CampeggiandoAppDelegate *appDelegate=(CampeggiandoAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


    appDelegate.latitudineDel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.5f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    appDelegate.longitudineDel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.5f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

}
```

When I run the compiler and the fitst view comes up the application broke and appears this exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate
>   setLatitudineDel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84210b0'

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: The class `CampeggiandoAppDelegate` does not the property `latitudineDel`. There is not wrong with `CLLocationManager`

Comment: it's wrong. on CampeggiandoAppDelegate I have NSString latitudineDel and longitudineDel

Comment: The error clearly states that `CampeggiandoAppDelegate` does not have an setter for the property `latitudineDel`. Either you have to property set to readonly or you the property is not defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your class interface should look like this before setting variables the way you do:

```
@interface CampeggiandoAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
// ...
// some ivars
// ...
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *latitudineDel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *longitudineDel;

@end
```

What you have for this moment is this:

```
@interface CampeggiandoAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
// ...
NSString *latitudineDel;
NSString *longitudineDel

// ...
}

@end
```

So there are no setters for those instance variables, that's why the exception is thrown.
For more information about properties read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).